# Existence of nontrivial categories in which every object is atomic

Tags: ct.category-theory, examples, counterexamples, cartesian-closed-categories

An object $X$ of a [cartesian closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+category) $\mathbf C$ is [atomic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/amazing+right+adjoint) if $({-})^X \colon \mathbf C \to \mathbf C$ has a right adjoint (hence is also [internally tiny](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object)). Intuitively, atomic objects are "very small" (as the name suggests), and consequently there aren't usually many tiny objects in $\mathbf C$.

However, is this necessarily the case? More precisely, do there exist any non-posetal cartesian closed categories in which every object is atomic?

If there are no non-posetal examples, are there any nontrivial posetal examples? (The terminal category forms a trivial example of a posetal example.)

Comment: Does it really imply tiny-ness ? It seems like this deduction uses that $*$ is tiny.

Comment: I think we can show that there is no cocomplete category where every object is tiny. What follows is only an idea: when a cocomplete category K has a dense generator of tiny objects G, then K is Psh(G). Because of course, K is dense in itself, we would obtain that K is its own presheaf category. I think one can show that is is never the case.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi: thanks, I have clarified that I meant "internally tiny"; I overlooked the distinction between the two notions.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti : I think there are two issues with your sketch : 1- as I pointed out above, atomic need not imply tiny, 2- The equivalence "K has a dense generator of tiny objects G iff K = Psh(G)" holds only if G is small: you cannot define Psh(G) -> K by left Kan extension otherwise, because you did not assume K had large colimits (in other words, for your full sketch you need K to have K-sized colimits, i.e. K must be a poset)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi do not forget the Wittgensteinian difference between to say and to show.

Comment: I think by very elementary manipulations one can prove that if $C$ has binary coproducts, and every element of $C$ is *tiny* (not atomic), then $C$ is a poset. This does not answer your question, though

Comment: Turns out I was looking in the wrong direction: I can prove the same thing with atomic in place of tiny

Comment: What are some examples of posetal cartesian closed categories where every object is atomic?

Comment: @TimCampion: I would also be interested to know if there are any such examples, if there are no nonposetal examples :) Maybe I'll cheekily update my question.

Answer (score 11):

Building on Maxime's answer -- if $C$ is cartesian closed and has an initial object $0$, and if $0$ is atomic (or even just tiny), then $C$ is the terminal category. For $1 = 0^0 = 0$ (the former equation holds in any cartesian closed category with an inital object $0$; the latter holds because $(-)^0$ preserves initial objects). That is, $C$ is pointed, and the only pointed cartesian closed category is the terminal one.

Comment: Thanks. I had spotted that having an initial object made the category pointed, but completely overlooked that this implied triviality.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happened for me :D that's a nice observation !

Answer (score 6):

This is a partial answer : if $C$ has finite coproducts, then $C$ must be posetal. In fact, I only need biproducts of the form $X\coprod X$.

Indeed, because $C$ is cartesian closed, $X\times -$ commutes with these coproducts and in particular it is easy to check that $\underline{\hom}(* \coprod *, Y)\cong Y \times Y$, naturally in $Y$ ($\underline\hom$ denotes the internal hom).

In particular, if $*\coprod *$ is atomic, the canonical morphism $(Y_0\times Y_0)\coprod (Y_1\times Y_1)\to (Y_0\times Y_0)\coprod (Y_0\times Y_1)\coprod (Y_1\times Y_0)\coprod (Y_1\times Y_1)$ is an isomorphim (here I'm denoting by $Y_0$ or $Y_1$ the same object $Y$, it's simply to indicate the "position", i.e. what the morphism is).

This morphism is of the form $X\overset{in_1}\to X\coprod X$, and the claim is that this is an isomorphism. This implies that any two morphisms $X\to Z$ must be equal: $\hom(X,Z)\times \hom(X,Z)\cong \hom(X,Z)$.

Here $X$ is $Y\times Y$, for an arbitrary $Y$. Any of the two projections $Y\times Y\to Y$ is split, so it follows that any two morphisms out of $Y$ must be equal. $Y$ was arbitrary, so $C$ is posetal.

Comment: Thank you, this is already very strong evidence that atomocity of every object is an extremely restrictive assumption. In other words, every tiny object must be ["superinitial"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subterminal+object) (assuming enough coproducts).